# set featured image option not appearing after adding theme support for custom post

Tags: wordpress

I am using the custom post type ui and advance custom field plugins to crate custom post type and fields.

I created the custom post type and also the fields. Then I did use the `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` in my functions.php file but the set featured image option is not appearing in my custom post type option.

For clarity I have attached some images  here:

As you can see the below mentioned image shows a custom post type but it is not allowing me to set any featured image.(no "set featured image" option on right side)

[image]

This image shows the custom fields that are created for the custom post type. Just to check that everything is correct.

I have set the rules to show the field group if post type is equal to portfolio.And I have also set the style to standard WP metabox.

[image]

The third image here is to make clear that I have enabled the featured image option for the custom post type.

[image]

So, can anyone please help why am I not getting the featured image option for my custom post types here?

Am I missing something?

Below is my functions.php file where I am adding theme support for post-thumbanils. Do I need to register post-thumbanails for my custom post types?

**functions.php:**

```
<?php

add_theme_support('menus');
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails');

function register_theme_menus(){
    register_nav_menus(
        array('primary-menu' => 'Primary Menu') 
    );
}

add_action('init','register_theme_menus');

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add thumbnail in array in `register_post_type()` function

> 'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail',
>   'excerpt', 'comments' )

```
$args = array(.......,
'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
    );

register_post_type( 'YOUR_POST_TYPE', $args );
```

Comment: thanks brother. Solved it. I was actually following a tutorial that didn't mention about the register_post_type and I thought it was not necessary.